# Unable to print formatted text using Bluetooth printer

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, thermal-printer, escpos, bluetooth-printing

I can able to print the text, Arabic characters but i am unable to print the formatted text like align center, bold text etc

I am using this plugin to print data https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial

below are the commands for align center and bold text.

```
TXT_ALIGN_CT: '\x1b\x61\x01', // Centering

TXT_BOLD_ON: '\x1b\x45\x01';
```

followed below steps :
1.using below function to convert string to byte

```
private getPrintData(TEXT: string) {

// based on http://ciaranj.blogspot.fr/2007/11/utf8-characters-encoding-in-javascript.html

var bytes = [];

for (var n = 0; n < TEXT.length; n++) {

  var c = TEXT.charCodeAt(n);

  if (c < 128) {

    bytes[bytes.length] = c;

  } else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {

    bytes[bytes.length] = (c >> 6) | 192;
    bytes[bytes.length] = (c & 63) | 128;

  } else {

    bytes[bytes.length] = (c >> 12) | 224;
    bytes[bytes.length] = ((c >> 6) & 63) | 128;
    bytes[bytes.length] = (c & 63) | 128;

  }

}

return bytes;
  }
```

---

```
const printData = this.getPrintData(getPrintData('你好'));

 this.printer.printData(printData ).then((success) => {});
```

its working fine.

**2. try to pass ESC/POS commands as hex code like below.**

```
   const data = new Uint8Array([0x2fa00bf0e86c440658a6a71]);
   this.printer.printData(data);
```

its not displaying bold text,

**can any one please help me ??**

Answer (score 1):

some of the printers doesn't supports the ESC/POS commands we have to use native sdks to resolve, i resolved by creating custom cordova plugin

Comment: Can you share your plugin repository ?

Comment: https://github.com/Surendra-thota/AisinoPosSdk